# how to apply text color everywhere

Tags: android, colors

I wan't to change all text colors to green. Is there a way to do this aside from copy-pasting android:textColor to every editText/TextView in the xml file? Or probably change the default color to green instead of black. Any help, Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create style and apply it everywhere or you can extend android TextView which will have green color as standard color

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add this to your app's theme definition:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff00ff00</item>
```

You can give a literal value or a color resource (`@color/foo`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very simple way to achieve this.

In AndroidManifext.xml, put this line in application tag

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

And define CustomTheme in style.xml under value folder

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks dude, it worked :D But how do I apply the same color on the text on editText and buttons?

Comment: For Button, you could use `<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>` in your theme. Define MyButtonStyle(with textColor) in style.xml. The idea is that this could be achieved using style/theme

Answer (score 0):

you can create custome style like this in styles.xml

```
<!--
 Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
 by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
     Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
     res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
     backward-compatibility can go here.


    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1.2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1.2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#F57025</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">5pt</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<!-- Custom Style defined for the buttons. -->
<style name="CustomButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">38dp</item>
</style>
```

And in manifest define that style

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```